# Verilog Timing Control(synchronization between modules)

Tags: synchronization, verilog

The code below is a simpler case of what I'm writing.

module `bar` will do something to `a` according to `operation`. The problem is, I can't get `result` correctly assigned (which should be assigned after output `b` of `foo1`).

I have found a workaround, just add `#1` before `result = r1`. I wonder what is the correct way to synchronize between modules?

```
module foo1(
  input a,
  output reg b
);
  always@(a)
    b = a;
endmodule

module foo2(
  input a,
  output reg b
);
  always@(a)
    b = ~a;
endmodule

module bar(
  input a,
  input operation,
  output b
);
  reg result;
  assign b = result;

  wire r1, r2;
  foo1 submod1(a, r1);
  foo2 submod2(a, r2);

  always@(a or operation) begin
    case (operation)
      1'b0:
        result = r1;
      1'b1:
        result = r2;
    endcase
  end

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("foobar.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, r1);
    $dumpvars(0, r2);
    $dumpvars(0, result);
    $dumpvars(0, operation);
  end
endmodule

module test;
  reg a, op;
  wire r;
  bar mod(a,op,r);

  integer i;
  initial begin
    a = 0;
    op = 0;
    for (i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
      #10 a = ~a;
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you might not be seeing proper propagation of the result is because your sensitivity list for result is not complete. You include a and operation by you really need to include r1 and r2 to have correct combinational logic. If you add them to the sensitivity list, it should operate as expected:

```
always@(operation or r1 or r2) begin
  case (operation)
    1'b0:
      result = r1;
    1'b1:
      result = r2;
  endcase
end
```

However, it is best if you cannot use SystemVerilog constructs like `always_comb` to at least use the Verilogs `always @(*)` to do combinational logic. That way, you dont risk missing sensitivity list items as you did this time.

Answer (score 1):

Your sensitivity list to assign `result` is incorrect. `always@(a or operation)` should be `always@(r1 or r2 or operation)` or `always @*`.

Verilog simulates everything out of order except for code placed in a procedural block (`begin`-`end`). This means `always@(a or operation)` can execute before `r1` and `r2` are updated.

For combinational logic I recommend using `always @*` (or `always @(*)` which is equivalent). This is a auto sensitivity list (ie figure out what should be in the sensitivity list for you) introduced in IEEE Std 1364-2001 which all modern simulator support. If you need to follow the IEEE Std 1364-1995 the use `always@(r1 or r2 or operation)`